# Can I fetch changes from more than one repo in git?

Tags: git, github, git-fetch

In git 2.3, we can git clone codes fast using --reference and --dissociate by borrowing objects from existing clones.

My question is can we make git fetch like that? Because under some poor network condition, git fetch from github will be very very slow. I want to make a mirror on my own server, so I can fast fetch from my own server but push codes to github.
If the mirror git repo is behind the github repo, the git could fetch from github automatically.

I mean, when git fetch, first check github repo , and then check if those newer objects exist in mirror repo, if exist, fetch from mirror, if not, fetch from github.

Comment: @user3159253 `git-remote`'s manpage has no mentions of a `--dissociate` flag.  And the git 2.3 release notes only mention `dissociate` in relation to `git-clone`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your origin as usual:

```
git remote set-url origin git://usr/to/mirrorr/<user>/<repo>.git
```

But change the push url to your GitHub repo

```
git remote set-url --push origin git://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

Comment: but the mirror may not sync with github repo asap. If I fetch from mirror repo, it may not the newest codes. I mean, first check github repo , and then check if those newer objects exist in mirror repo, if exist, fetch from mirror, if not, fetch from github.

Comment: @user392412 then you can add a second remote (referencing github, named '`github`') and fetch from that second remote *after* having fetch from the mirror. The first fetch will be fast you can start merging/working immediately. The second fetch will be slower (can be done in background) and you can later on compare `github/master` with `origin/master` to see if there are any differences.